# $state.current different values when $state injected in onEnter()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my code:

```
angular.module("LearnRouter", ["ui.router"])

.config(['$stateProvider',
  function(stateProvider) {

    stateProvider.state('state1', {
      controller: function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.state3 = function() {
          $state.go('state3');
        }
      },
      template: "<h1><i>Template1</i><div ui-view><button type='button' ng-click=state3()>State 3</button></div></h1>",
      availableOptions:["option1","option2","option3"]
    });

    stateProvider.state('state2', {
      template: "<h1>Template2</h1>"
    });

    stateProvider.state('state3', {
      parent: "state1",
      template: "<h1>Template3<div>Names: <span ng-bind=names></span</div></h1>",
      controller: function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.names=$state.current.availableOptions;
      },
      onEnter:function($state){
        console.log($state)
      }
    });
  }
])


.service('namesRepo', function() {

  this.fetch = function() {
    return ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
  }

})

.controller("IndexController", ["$scope", "$state",
  function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.state1 = function() {
      $state.go('state1');
    }

    $scope.state2 = function() {
      $state.go('state2');
    }
  }
]);
```

It's simple javascript representing usage of angular-ui-router.

I wanted to test whether the child state inherits custom fields from the parent state.
Obviously i came to the conclusion it doesn't or at least my results are showing this.

As seen from the code I pass $state to the onEnter function. Since the state is entered (or at least this is how i understand the things), current state must be state3. Even the console.log approve that understanding

[image: This is the result from the console.log($state)]

So when i try to console.log($state.current) the result is something different. It gives me that the parent state is the current one.

[image: This is the result from the console.log($state.current)]

Comment: States do not inherit arbitrary attributes.  However, the `data` attribute of a state declaration is prototypally inherited.  See the docs for [$stateProvider.state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider), specifically the 'data' attribute

Answer (score 2):

`onEnter` and `onExit` callbacks are invoked while the transition is still *in process*.  `$state.current` is not updated until the transition is fully *complete*.  Once the transition is complete, `$state.current` is set to the "to" state, $stateChangeSuccess is called, and the controllers are invoked.

As such, `$state.current` contains the "from" state during `onEnter` and `onExit`.

Comment: How will you comment that when i log the whole $state object , the value for current is actually state3 and when i log $state.current it's state1.

Comment: Because chrome is lazy evaluating $state.current in the console when you expand it.  You are expanding it AFTER the transition is completed.   Put a breakpoint immediately after your console.log($state), then check the value of $state.current.name, it will be 'state1'

Comment: Ok, today i'm gonna test what you have suggested. Thank for now